# What does the concurrent number mean in the web site?

Tags: concurrency

I often hear about that some website like facebook has over 100000 concurrent number.

I googled a lot and find someome explain it means 100000 request simultaneously send to the server. But I want to konw what does the 'simultaneously' mean? Does it demand that the requests sent to the server should be within one second?

Thanks

Comment: When you do two things simultaneously, what does it mean? That you have to have them done within a second - or that you have to start the second before you finished the first?

Comment: I mean the server accept request from different user simultaneously

Comment: like the function of ab - Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool

Comment: this link may be helpful for you . http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/2011/02/load-testing-basics-how-many-concurrent-users-is-enough/